# How to POST a form and change the page in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have a form that allows the user to enter keys and values, with buttons to add a new row and remove a row. A Key and Value pair is a json object. All of these key/value pairs are stored in an array.

I want to submit this form and send this data to the backend in JSON form, and go to a new page, like a regular normal form. I do not want to use AJAX.

For example, a regular HTML form that can POST data to the backend without AJAX:

```
<form action="/path/to/page" method="POST">
    <input name="key_1" /> <input name="value_1"><br />
    ...
    <button type="submit">
</form>
```

The problem with this approach above is that my back end needs to parse out _1, from `key_1` and `value_1` to know that they are matched together. I would like to use JSON to ameiliorate the backend from having to do this.

Currently I have code like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myApp', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.pairs = [{'key': 'foo', 'value': 'bar'}];
    $scope.submit = function() {
        $http.post('path/to/page/', JSON.stringify({'fields': $scope.pairs}))
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log("Success");
        });
    }
}
```

However this is calling the request using AJAX and is not changing the page.

Can I submit a regular, non-ajax, form with Angular such that I can send a JSON to the backend?

Comment: Why can't you just use window.location.href = urlOfNextPage inside the success callback?

Comment: No, if the post causes a full page reload, you cannot guarantee the backend to finish the process. If you *must not* use ajax (for example the "Requested-With" header is forbidden on the service), you can still use iframes.

Comment: @Vi100 If I add this under the .then...successCallback section, it posts the POST request via ajax and then sends me to the same page using GET. I want to call the /path/to/page using regular POST form submission instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can change url as usual with js `$window.location.href = "/yourPage"`

or make you html as normal form with action and submit it if that is what you want.

```
<form action="/yourPage" method="post"></form>
```

Comment: If I add this under the `.then...successCallback` section, it posts the POST request via ajax and then sends me to the same page using GET. I want to call the `/path/to/page` using regular POST form submission.

Comment: Then do a form.submit()

Comment: I would like to submit a JSON to the backend rather than submitting keys and values that have to be parsed. I updated my question to clarify this.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen You are mixing two different protocols: you either send HTTP POST (the whole form data) or send AJAX/JSON.

Comment: P.S. you can also put a hidden field in the form and make its value `JSON.stringify({'fields': $scope.pairs})` then post the form with js and handle json parameter